# How to access Azure PostgreSQL using private IP

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

In Azure environment, I have added one PostgreSQL services using Azure Database for PostgreSQL servers. It is using a public IP Network When I try to connect this PostgreSQL instance from one of the Azure VM. I need the connection in the following way.

1. PostgreSQL instance is not having any public IP
2. Need to connect this instance from Azure VM's only using private IP Network

How can we achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot achieve this for now.

Because It is not currently possible to join a Postgre SQL to a VNet. **But Azure Database for PostgreSQL Team has started working on it**:

> 1. **VNET service end point GA target is H1 CY2018**.
> 2. Public preview for read replicas in a subset of the regions is expected around the service GA date.

You can see the details in [this Uservoice page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/597976-azure-database-for-postgresql/suggestions/32789044-ga-timeline-already-2018).

Hope this helps!